# Efficiently rearranging data from list of data frames into arrays in R?

Tags: r, performance, dataframe

**I have data that is arranged as follows**:

- A list
- Inside the list, every element is a data frame (50 data frames)
- Each of those data frames contains 5 rows of numbers, with 9 named columns (same 9 names for all 50 data frames)

My **goal is to efficiently rearrange this data such that**:

- The "second dimension" (ranging from 1 to 5 in the description above) becomes the first dimension.
- The "first dimension" (ranging from 1 to 50 in the description above) becomes the second dimension.
- I only keep some of the 9 named columns (the rest can be discarded), selected by name
- I want all the numbers to be stored in an array (or another even more efficient data structure is fine too), instead of these inefficient lists and data frames.

---

**Example data** can be generated using the following code (simplified to have only 2 data frames of 5 rows and 3 columns each):

```
example_list<-lapply(X=1:2, FUN=function(X){setNames(data.frame(X*c(1:5), -X*c(1:5), X*100*c(1:5)), c("C1", "C2", "C3"))})
```

This creates a list of the following two data frames:

```
> example_list[1]

  C1 C2  C3
1  1 -1 100
2  2 -2 200
3  3 -3 300
4  4 -4 400
5  5 -5 500

> example_list[2]

  C1  C2   C3
1  2  -2  200
2  4  -4  400
3  6  -6  600
4  8  -8  800
5 10 -10 1000
```

---

My **current solution** (with hardcoded numbers for the example data) looks as follows. In this case, I assume we only care about the columns named "C1" and "C2":

```
important_cols <- c("C1", "C2")
result <- array(0, c(5, 2, length(important_cols)))
for(i in 1:5){
    for(j in 1:2){
        result[i,j,] <- c(example_list[[j]][i,important_cols], recursive=T)
    }
}
```

Which gives the following output:

```
> result
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    2    4
[3,]    3    6
[4,]    4    8
[5,]    5   10

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   -1   -2
[2,]   -2   -4
[3,]   -3   -6
[4,]   -4   -8
[5,]   -5  -10
```

where, for example, `result[5,2,] = [10, -10]` corresponds to the `5`th row of the `2`nd dataframe of the original data (with third column removed).

---

The above solution works, **but I can't help but suspect that there should be a significantly more efficient solution** than the double manually-implemented for-loop and setting all the elements one-by-one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some `lapply` and `purrr::transpose` to avoid the loop:

```
# Example
N <- 1e5
example_list <-
  lapply(
    X = 1:2,
    FUN = function(X) {
      setNames(data.frame(X * c(1:N), -X * c(1:N), X * 100 * c(1:N)), c("C1", "C2", "C3"))
    }
  )

important_cols <- c("C1", "C2")    

# Your solution -> 58 seconds :O
system.time({
  result <- array(0, c(N, 2, length(important_cols)))
  for(i in 1:N){
    for(j in 1:2){
      result[i,j,] <- c(example_list[[j]][i,important_cols], recursive=T)
    }
  }
})

# Solution with purrr::transpose -> 0 sec    
library(magrittr)  ## for the %>%
system.time({
  result2 <- example_list %>%
    lapply(function(df) df[important_cols]) %>%
    purrr::transpose() %>%
    sapply(function(l) do.call(cbind, l))
})
dim(result2) <- c(nrow(example_list[[1]]), 
                  length(example_list), 
                  length(important_cols))

# Verification
all.equal(result, result2)
```

Comment: That seems to work well! For the sake of completess, would you mind editing in a `library(purrr)` (I guess I could edit it in myself too, but it's your answer...)

Comment: Yeah, I explicitly used `purrr::` here. You can load the package if you want.

Comment: Ah I see. Initially it didn't work for me, but that was because I also still needed to run `install.packages(purrr)`. After that I also immediately ran `library(purrr)` since I figured that'd be necessary too. Not very familiar with R yet.

Comment: After looking more closely, it actually doesn't seem to work. Let `(I, J, K)` denote the dimensions of the original data, with `K` being the number of important cols in the dataframes. The goal was to get data arranged as `(J, I, K)`, preferably in an array (don't want to deal with inefficient list/dataframe indexing afterwards anymore). Your solution gives me `(K, J, I)`, with the outer structure still being a list

Comment: Sorry but what you wanted was really not clear ("I want all the numbers to be stored in an array (or another even more efficient data structure is fine too)"). Basically what I had was perfectly equivalent with what you had (with a list instead of the third dimension). Just use a `sapply` instead and change the dimensions of the result if you really want an array.. (see my edit)

Comment: Yes now it seems fine, in particular with the `dim` at the end (getting the correct ''memory layout'' was the most important point for me)